# Fastest way to compare a number to a list of numbers in a range?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there a method faster in performance than doing this:

```
var value = 2432; 

if (value >= 20 && value <= 31) return true;
else if (value >= 45 && value <= 47) return true;
else if (value >= 82 && value <= 86) return true;
...
else if (value >= 1052 && value <= 1065) return true;
else if (value >= 2400 && value <= 2500) return true;
```

The conditional statements contain numbers that aren't in a pattern. The numbers go up to 65,000. Also the ranges are variable and don't intersect each other. The range is stored in a SQL database:

```
columns: from, to
rows: [21, 59], [92, 280], etc...
```

I was initially thinking of creating a lookup table containing all the numbers between the ranges (e.g., `[20, 21, 21, 23, ... 31, -> 45, 46 47]`).

Is there a better way?

Comment: It depends. Are the ranges fixed? Will you be testing multiple numbers in the same ranges?

Comment: Also define "faster". Faster to code? Faster execution time?

Comment: Okay so the distance of the ranges seem totally variable, and if it's in the range you just want them to return `true`?

Comment: I forgot to clarify - the ranges are not fixed but variable. If a value is within the range, it must return true.

Comment: different ranges don't intersect with each other, is it correct assumption?

Comment: You might do it in SQL

Comment: @mhodges at present I auto generate these conditional statements (too much to write) from the SQL database. Performance is the key metric.

Comment: @skyboyer that is correct, there is no intersection.

Comment: Since they don't intersect you may consider constructing a tree for the ranges if you're going to change the ranges significantly less than you'll check the condition.

Comment: @mhodges and I'd add _"faster to write"?_ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if ranges are unique and don't intersect with each other.
The fastest way to check I see to be next algo:

1. make a list of pairs [start, end] or just use two separated lists for start points and end points.
2. sort them(it could be done really easy on SQL side)
3. using binary search find out first `start` value that is larger than your reference number
4. previous item give your just single range you should check against your reference number.

If sorting is done on DB side, then this algo will be O(logN) that is fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

You could make an array of `[start, end]` arrays:

```
const ranges = [
    [20, 31],
    [45, 47],
    [82, 86],
    // …
    [1052, 1065],
    [2400, 2500]
  ];
```

Then use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find a range that a `value` is in (e.g. `let value = 2432;`):

```
ranges.find(([start, end]) => value >= start && value <= end); // Returns `[2400, 2500]`, which is the range the value is in, or
!!ranges.find(([start, end]) => value >= start && value <= end); // Returns `true`, since the value is in a range, or
ranges.some(([start, end]) => value >= start && value <= end); // Returns `true`, since the value is in a range, or
```

Comment: Love how concise this is. I could probably speed this up by replacing .find with a for-loop too.

Comment: @John Find bails on first match, so you likely wouldn't see any improvement using a for loop.

Comment: @ShaunH Although I used a functional approach in my answer too, technically OP is right that functions produce stack overhead, so the for loop would be more efficient. That being said, if you are that concerned about performance, you either A: have tens/hundreds of millions of records, or B: probably should not be using JavaScript in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do the query in sql and there is no intersection, then just have a table with all possible values between 1 and 65000 and have a bool column if the number is valid with indices.  You only really take a hit on an update performance wise.
In this case do:

```
Value isRange
1     true
```

SELECT * FROM RangeTable where Value = @Value and isRange = true

This optimizes for reading, however if you update frequently then this will not help.

Are  you updating frequently?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly reduce the number of conditional statements you have to write.

Assuming your "from-to" arrays arrive from the server in the form `[ [n1, n2], [n3, n4], ... ]`, you can loop over each of your ranges and `return` from the function once you have a match, or return false otherwise:

```
let ranges = [ [20, 31], [45, 47] ];
let valueInRange = 46;
let valueNotInRange = 33;

function isValInRange(value, rangeArr) {
    for(let i = 0; i < rangeArr.length; i++) {
        if(value >= rangeArr[0] && value <= rangeArr[1]) {
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(isValInRange(valueInRange, ranges)); //true
console.log(isValInRange(valueNotInRange, ranges)); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be checking against these values significantly more than you'll update them, one option would be to construct a tree with the ranges and search it a little faster than iterating through all of the options. You will want to keep the tree balanced, though, or it won't do you much good.

```
/*
  Construct this dynamically
  min: range minimum
  max: range maximum
  lt: node for ranges less than this range
  gt: node for ranges greater than this range
  I'd probably make a class for this.
*/
const ranges = {
  min: 82,
  max: 86,
  lt: {
    min: 45,
    max: 47,
    lt: {
      min: 20,
      max: 31
    }
  },
  gt: {
    min: 2400,
    max: 2500,
    lt: {
      min: 1052,
      max: 1065
    }
  }
};

function lookup(value) {
  let current = ranges;
  while (current) {
    if (value < current.min) {
      current = current.lt;
    } else if (value > current.max) {
      current = current.gt;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This essentially does this for the value:

1. Go to middle range.
2. If current node is null, return false (value not in any range).
3. If value is in current range, return true (value is in range).
4. If value is less than current min, go to middle range less than current and go back to step 2.
5. If value is greater than current max, go to middle range greater than current and go back to step 2.