# Which method should I use to compare values in array of objects? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Help me solve an assignment.

Array of objects is given:

```
let classTime = [
   { start: 10, end: 25},
   { start: 20, end: 40},
   { start: 35, end: 50}
] 
requires 2 classrooms
```

Each object represents class start time and class end time. If two intervals overlap, two classrooms are required. I need to determine how many classrooms are required to keep classes going.

Im confused if I should use .forEach() method or .reduce(). Pls help!

Comment: please show what you have tried at least

Comment: Here is a direction: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51866062/863110. And BTW, the smallest challenge is `forEach` vs `reduce`. You can do that with both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a classroom cannot accommodate two classes if the second starts at exactly the same time the first ends.
Try this code:

```
function classesRequired(classTime) {
  var times={};
  for(var classObject of classTime) {
    if(times[classObject.start]==undefined) times[classObject.start]=0;
    if(times[classObject.end]==undefined) times[classObject.end]=0;
  }

  for(var classObject of classTime) {
    for(var key of Object.keys(times)) {
      if((key>=classObject.start) && (key<=classObject.end)) times[key]++;
    }
  }

  var classes=Object.values(times).sort((a,b)=>b-a)[0];

  console.log(classes);

  return classes;
}
```

We've created `times` object to hold all `start` and `end` times.
Then we iterate over `classTime` objects, and `times` keys, increasing value if within, including, `start` and `end`.
Then we sort the `values` in a descending order, grabbing the first = largest, logging and returning it.
Enjoy!